# std::is_same absurd behaviour on type equality check

Tags: c++, is-same

Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    using type = int;
    using reference = int&;
};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::type&, A::reference>); // <-- Success, as it would be
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const A::type&, const A::reference>); // <-- Fail!!
```

What is going on?? Why they are not the same type anymore? I spent lot of time finding this and it really seems a compiler bug

Comment: `const A::reference` tries to `const`-ify the reference itself, which is invalid but is silenced to a no-op when a typedef is involved.

Comment: Another case of leading const misleading people

Comment: So how do I solve it?

Comment: `std::add_lvalue_reference_t<const std::remove_reference_t<A::reference>>` or `decltype(std::as_const(std::declval<A::reference>()))`.

Comment: @storyteller West const worst const east const best const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `const int&` is, so to speak, a reference to constant int, not a constant reference to int. Thus adding `const` keyword to `A::reference` produces a beast that spelled as `int& const` instead of `const int&` (or equally fine `int const &`).

So yes, as a reference cannot be rebound to different object, it is de facto constant without any keywords. Thus that `const` after an ampersand is excessive. Looks like it is silently dropped, I cannot cite standard on required compiler behavior, see comment by @Quentin.

Second, the answer may depend on what you really want to achieve. If `A` is a container, it should have a `A::const_reference` member type, which you should use. If it is a more generic range rather than a container, its `reference` and `const_reference` member types might be two completely unrelated proxy object classes. If you control `A`, add a `const_reference` member type. Otherwise, @Evg provided a solution that will do. Maybe a more simple solution is just `const std::decay_t<A::reference>&`.